# I want to change the parent's member data to an instance of another class

Tags: c++, class

In C++, I have a class `A`, and a class `B`.

In class `A`, there is a object (of class `B`) , I want to change the class `A` member data in the object of class `B`. How can I do that ?

I want to do this:

```
class A {
    public:
      A() {
          new B(this); 
      }
    private:
      int i;
};

class B {
  public:
     B(A* parent) {
        this->parent = parent;
     }

     change() {
         parent->i = 5;
     }
private:
     A* parent;
};
```

Comment: There isn't actually a B object in A, because you don't save it. What are you *really* trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than setting B as a friend class to A, a better method to preserve encapsulation would be to add a setter method to class A.

Your class A would then look somewhat like this:

```
class A {
    public:
      A() {
          new B(this); 
      }

      void set_i(int value)
      {
         i = value;
      }
    private:
      int i;
};
```

Then in your class B implementation, call set_i().

```
class B {
  public:
     B(A* parent) {
        this->parent = parent;
     }

     change() {
         parent->set_i(5);
     }
private:
     A* parent;
};
```

This way you're not exposing and relying on private implementation details of class A in class B.

Answer (score 3):

In declaration of class `A` you need to define class `B` as a friend:

```
friend class B;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
class A {
    friend class B;
private:
   int i;
public:
   A() : i(0) {
       new B(this); 
   }
};
```